Excel VBA, create a connector between two shapes that avoids crossing a third shape
I need some Excel VBA code that will create a connector to connect two shapes (A & C).
Shape B is between shapes A & C and the connector must go around shape B not across it.
Anybody have any idea?
Here is my code to create a connector between two existing shapes.
Public Function func_CreateConnectors(ByVal strSheetName As String, ByVal strShape1Name As String, ByVal strShape2Name As String, ByVal strConnectorName As String, ByVal dbConnectorWeight As Double)
Dim s1 As Shape, s2 As Shape, connectorShape As Shape
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSheetName)

'Get a reference to start and end shape.
Set s1 = ws.Shapes(strShape1Name)
Set s2 = ws.Shapes(strShape2Name)

'Create a connector (position and size don't matter).
Set connectorShape = ws.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorCurve, 1, 1, 1, 1)

'Connect to each shape.
With connectorShape
    .ConnectorFormat.BeginConnect s1, 2
    .ConnectorFormat.EndConnect s2, 2
    .Line.Weight = dbConnectorWeight
    .Name = strConnectorName
    .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 255)
    .RerouteConnections
End With

End Function
The image shows the desired outcome.


It is still a bit rough around the edges and needs tidying up and testing for unusual situations but it seems to be working nicely. it doesnt answer the original question as written but it does answer the requirement.
Public Function func_CreateFreehandConnections(ByVal strSheetName As String, ByVal strShape1Name As String, ByVal strShape2Name As String, ByVal strNameShapeToAvoid As String, ByVal strConnectorName As String, ByVal dbConnectorWeight As Double, ByVal strConnectorColour As String)
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSheetName)
'Get a reference to start shape, end shape, and shape to avoid.
Dim sStartShape As Shape: Set sStartShape = ws.Shapes(strShape1Name)
Dim sEndShape As Shape: Set sEndShape = ws.Shapes(strShape2Name)
Dim sShapeToAvoid As Shape: Set sShapeToAvoid = ws.Shapes(strNameShapeToAvoid)

If sStartShape.Left > sEndShape.Left Then
    connectStartPosX = sStartShape.Left
    connectEndPosX = sEndShape.Left + sEndShape.Width
Else
    connectStartPosX = sStartShape.Left + sStartShape.Width
    connectEndPosX = sEndShape.Left
End If

connectStartPosY = sStartShape.Top + sStartShape.Height / 2
connectEndPosY = sEndShape.Top + sEndShape.Height / 2

dbShapeToAvoidTop = sShapeToAvoid.Top
dbShapeToAvoidLeft = sShapeToAvoid.Left

dbShapeToAvoidMiddle = sShapeToAvoid.Top + sShapeToAvoid.Height / 2

dbShapeToAvoidBottom = sShapeToAvoid.Top + sShapeToAvoid.Height
dbShapeToAvoidRight = sShapeToAvoid.Left + sShapeToAvoid.Width


    With ws.Shapes.BuildFreeform(msoEditingAuto, connectStartPosX, connectStartPosY) 'create starting node (node 1)
    .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, connectStartPosX + 10, connectStartPosY 'create node 2
    If connectStartPosX < dbShapeToAvoidLeft And connectEndPosX < dbShapeToAvoidLeft Then
        'do nothing
    ElseIf connectStartPosX > dbShapeToAvoidRight And connectEndPosX > dbShapeToAvoidRight Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        If connectStartPosY < dbShapeToAvoidMiddle And connectEndPosY < dbShapeToAvoidMiddle Then
            .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, connectStartPosX + 10, dbShapeToAvoidTop 'create node 3
            .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, connectEndPosX - 10, dbShapeToAvoidTop 'create node 4
        ElseIf connectStartPosY > dbShapeToAvoidMiddle And connectEndPosY > dbShapeToAvoidMiddle Then
            .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, connectStartPosX + 10, dbShapeToAvoidBottom 'create node 3
            .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, connectEndPosX - 10, dbShapeToAvoidBottom 'create node 4
        Else
            .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, connectStartPosX + 10, dbShapeToAvoidTop 'create node 3
            .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, connectEndPosX - 10, dbShapeToAvoidTop 'create node 4
        End If
    End If
    
    .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, connectEndPosX - 10, connectEndPosY 'create node 3 or 5
    .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, connectEndPosX, connectEndPosY 'last position (node 4 or 6
    '.AddNodes msoSegmentCurve, msoEditingAuto, 175, 25
    .ConvertToShape.Select
End With
    With Selection.ShapeRange
    .Name = "conn_" & sStartShape.Name & sEndShape.Name
    .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
    .Line.Visible = msoTrue
    
     If UCase(Trim(strConnectorColour)) = "RED" Then
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    ElseIf UCase(Trim(strConnectorColour)) = "GREEN" Then
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    ElseIf UCase(Trim(strConnectorColour)) = "BLUE" Then
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    ElseIf UCase(Trim(strConnectorColour)) = "YELLOW" Then
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    ElseIf UCase(Trim(strConnectorColour)) = "PURPLE" Then
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 255)
    ElseIf UCase(Trim(strConnectorColour)) = "CYAN" Then
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 255)
    Else
        'default colour
    End If
    
    .Line.Transparency = 0
    .Line.Weight = dbConnectorWeight
End With

End Function

As far as I know, there is no direct way to obtain the routing coordinates of a connector. The only properties you can access are its width, height, and top and left coordinates.

You can approximately calculate the midpoint of the connector using its start and end points, although this approach won’t be perfectly accurate.
Here’s a sample code snippet to calculate the midpoint coordinates from the connector’s start and end points:
Sub GetConnectorMidPoint()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim connectorShape As shape
    Dim startX As Double, startY As Double
    Dim endX As Double, endY As Double
    Dim midX As Double, midY As Double
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change to your sheet name
    Set connectorShape = ws.Shapes("Connector") ' Change to your connector's name

    ' Get the starting point (X, Y)
    startX = connectorShape.ConnectorFormat.BeginConnectedShape.Left + connectorShape.ConnectorFormat.BeginConnectedShape.Width / 2
    startY = connectorShape.ConnectorFormat.BeginConnectedShape.Top + connectorShape.ConnectorFormat.BeginConnectedShape.Height / 2
    
    ' Get the ending point (X, Y)
    endX = connectorShape.ConnectorFormat.EndConnectedShape.Left + connectorShape.ConnectorFormat.EndConnectedShape.Width / 2
    endY = connectorShape.ConnectorFormat.EndConnectedShape.Top + connectorShape.ConnectorFormat.EndConnectedShape.Height / 2
    
    ' Calculate the midpoint
    midX = (startX + endX) / 2
    midY = (startY + endY) / 2
    
    ' Output the coordinates of the midpoint
    Debug.Print "Midpoint X: " & midX
    Debug.Print "Midpoint Y: " & midY
End Sub

Midpoint X: 406.5
Midpoint Y: 159

You could use this midpoint and compare it to the properties of any "blocking shape," adjusting the curvature of the connector iteratively by modifying the .ConnectorFormat.Parent.Adjustments.Item(1) property. However, this method may not be very reliable for precise routing.
If there’s a more accurate and reliable way to achieve this, I’d be very interested to learn about it as well.

I had a similar problem a while ago, I wish VBA had more control over routing connectors.  Good luck.

I dont think your suggestion is going to give me the level of control I require, but it did give me an idea.
There is a method called BuildFreeform which allows you to create lines and curves (specifying the node positions) and join them into a shape.
True the shapes created wont be connectors but the important part for my use case is that they go around the blocking shape.
I have done a quick test and it looks promising, if it goes further i will post the code.

This is a very slow F8-debug of the code

presented below:-
Sub Routine()
    Const topOffset As Single = 75
    Const leftOffset As Single = 60
    Const size As Single = 60

    With ActiveSheet
        Dim leftSquare As Shape
        Set leftSquare = .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, leftOffset, topOffset * 1.75, size, size)
        Dim oval As Shape
        Set oval = .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, leftOffset + size * 2, topOffset, size * 3, size * 3)
        Dim rightSquare As Shape
        Set rightSquare = .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, leftOffset + size * 6, topOffset * 1.75, size, size)
            With .Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorElbow, 10, 10, 10, 10)
                .ConnectorFormat.BeginConnect leftSquare, 1
                .ConnectorFormat.EndConnect rightSquare, 1
                .Adjustments.Item(1) = topOffset * 1.25
                .Line.Weight = 2
                .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End With
    End With

End Sub

